# How to hide machine name from displaying in terminal session screen

Tags: command-line, gnome

[image: terminal]

As you can see from the screenshot, my entire machine name (looks like a key) gets displayed whenever I invoke a terminal session.

Is there any way to avoid or hide it?

Comment: Try something from [this article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/) ;)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes. Open `~/.bashrc` file from terminal with:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Find this line (in my case is somewhere at line 60):

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

and replace it with:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

As you can see, the most important thing is to delete `\h` (which stands for hostname) from PS1 if you want to hide machine name from displaying in terminal.

Save the file and close it. Restart the terminal, or just type:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: `\h` means hostname, right?

Comment: @Braiam yes, as well as `\u` means  username.

Comment: Can I do the same with the terminal window title?

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: If you want to remove it from the window title as well, do the same in the section next to that line (where it checks whether it is an xterm or not, line 69).

Comment: Is it possible without editing a file?

Answer (score 0):

Simply open your `.bashrc` then change line started with `PS1=` before `case "$TERM"` to `PS1="anything"`.

> `sudo nano .bashrc` 
> `#PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"`
> `PS1="anything"`

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save changes.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work both of the answers for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

So I tried this, and it worked:

1. Open the `bashrc` file
2. At the very bottom of the `bashrc` file, add the below line:
   `export PS1=”\W \$”`
3. Save it
4. `source ~/.bashrc` or reopen the terminal

- [Source](https://jilaxzone.com/2022/09/10/linux-tip-heres-how-to-hide-computer-name-and-username-in-terminal-command-prompt/)
- [For More customization](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/)