# How do I hide the hostname in my terminal

Tags: command-line, zsh, prompt

I'm using zsh with powerlevel9k theme and I would like to know how to remove hostname from my terminal.
This is how my terminal looks right now:

[image: screenshot]

I would like to change it to only show `kathi` instead of `kathi@Quantiphi-927`.

I don't have the PS1 line in my `.zshrc` file and [adding the PS1 line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338501/how-to-hide-machine-name-from-displaying-in-terminal-session-screen) makes no difference.
I tried:

```
export PS1="\u\W\\$ "
```

and

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Comment: Please [edit] and provide your current `PS1`, e.g. by adding the respective line from your `.zshrc` file.

Comment: Start with common mistakes: Did you remember to reload your .bashrc after editing?

Comment: yes i did ttry reloading by both opening a new terminal and using ~source .zshrc

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/), simply run `p10k configure`.

If you are using the original Powerlevel9k (you'll know it if your prompt is slow), type this:

```
echo 'POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(dir vcs)` >>! ~/.zshrc
exec zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `Powerlevel9k`, there is a variable called `POWERLEVEL9K_CONTEXT_TEMPLATE` that you can change to hide the hostname.

the default option for `POWERLEVEL9K_CONTEXT_TEMPLATE` is `%n@%m`, `%n` for `username` and `%m` for the machine.

to hide the hostname:

1. Open the `~/.zshrc`  :  `sudo nano ~/.zshrc`
2. add `POWERLEVEL9K_CONTEXT_TEMPLATE="%n"` at the end of `.zshrc` file.
3. save the file.

you will get a result like below:

[image]

for more information please check the [powerlevel9k#context](https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k#context) documentation.